# ColdFusion ReportBuilder 9 nvr_win error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I recently upgraded to 64-bit Enterprise ColdFusion 9 running in a multi-server JRun environment on Windows 2008 Server. When I try to invoke a .cfr that worked perfectly in ColdFusion 8, I get the following error in my server log:

> Unable to load library: nvr_win:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native
>   Library
>   X:\JRun4\servers\server1\cfusion.ear\cfusion.war\WEB-INF\cfusion\lib\nvr_win64.dll
>   already loaded in another classloader

*Judging from that error, it looks like there is some collision between 32-bit and 64-bit libraries.*

I then end up with this message on the cfm page that calls the cfr:

> Unable to execute report decoding
>   function:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   coldfusion.util.ReportDecoder.getReport([B)[B

I tried loading the .cfr in the ColdFusion 9 ReportBuilder, resaving and using that, but that didn't change anything. This is happening on multiple (all?) .cfr files on my site. Please help!

Here is the full stack trace:

> java.io.IOException: Unable to execute
>   report decoding function:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   coldfusion.util.ReportDecoder.getReport([B)[B
>   at
>   coldfusion.compiler.TemplateReader.getReport(TemplateReader.java:259)
>   at
>   coldfusion.compiler.TemplateReader.(TemplateReader.java:74)
>   at
>   coldfusion.compiler.TemplateReader.(TemplateReader.java:42)
>   at
>   coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslationContext.getPageReader(NeoTranslationContext.java:661)
>   at
>   coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.translateJava(NeoTranslator.java:320)
>   at
>   coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.translateJava(NeoTranslator.java:144)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader$TemplateCache$1.fetch(TemplateClassLoader.java:424)
>   at
>   coldfusion.util.LruCache.get(LruCache.java:180)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader$TemplateCache.fetchSerial(TemplateClassLoader.java:362)
>   at
>   coldfusion.util.AbstractCache.fetch(AbstractCache.java:58)
>   at
>   coldfusion.util.SoftCache.get_statsOff(SoftCache.java:133)
>   at
>   coldfusion.util.SoftCache.get(SoftCache.java:81)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader.findClass(TemplateClassLoader.java:591)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader.newInstance(TemplateClassLoader.java:540)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader.newInstance(TemplateClassLoader.java:523)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.getCFCInstance(TemplateProxyFactory.java:270)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:173)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:158)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:148)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:132)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveFile(TemplateProxyFactory.java:109)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.report.Report.(Report.java:135)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.report.Report.(Report.java:146)
>   at
>   coldfusion.tagext.lang.ReportTag.doEndTag(ReportTag.java:596)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2723)
>   at
>   cfrequestprint2ecfm1848352526.runPage([path-to-my-web-files]\requestprint.cfm:8)
>   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
>   at
>   coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:363)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
>   at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
>   at
>   jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
>   at
>   com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.b(FusionReactorFilter.java:376)
>   at
>   com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.c(FusionReactorFilter.java:254)
>   at
>   com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorFilter.java:164)
>   at
>   jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
>   at
>   coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
>   at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>   at
>   jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
>   at
>   jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
>   at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
>   at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
>   at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
>   at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
>   at
>   jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
>   at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
>   at
>   jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)

Comment: Note that restarting the ColdFusion process cleared up the issue for now. But that's not a solution--that's a bandaid. I need to know what caused this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the error means your missing a native library. The file name missing starts with libnvr. The rest of the filename depends on your OS. EX: Linux libnvr_linux.so, libnvr_linux64.so; OS X libnvr_osx.jnilib; etc.

The file should be in your /WEB-INF/cfusion/lib folder.

In your case, you may have the file in two places, both in the class path for Java and Coldfusion. You'd need to search your filesystem for the files and remove the one you don't need.